# Discussion with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

ia_answers= "trolol"
input_frame = LabelFrame(window, text="User :", borderwidth=4)
input_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(input_frame, text=input_user)
input_field.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

ia_frame = LabelFrame(window, text="Discussion",borderwidth = 15, height = 100, width = 100)
ia_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP)

user_says = StringVar()
user_text = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=user_says, anchor = NE, justify =   RIGHT, bg="white") 
user_text.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP) 

ia_says = StringVar()
ia_text = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=ia_says, anchor = W, justify = LEFT, bg="white") 
ia_text.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM) 

def Enter_pressed(event):
    """Took the current string in the Entry field."""
    input_get = input_field.get()
    input_user.set("")
    user_says.set(input_get + "\n\n")
    ia_says.set(ia_answers)

input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
window.mainloop()
```

Hi, i am trying to build a discussion Bot.

When I execute the code, the question in the input field and the answer get displayed correctly.

The problem is after entering the next sentence, the previous question/answer gets removed. Here is an example:

```
Hello Bot
Hello User
(then the text disappears)
How are you
Fine thank you
```

What i want :

```
Hello Bot
Hello User
(then the text stays in the frame)
How are you
Fine thank you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs in line -

```
user_says.set(input_get + "\n\n")
ia_says.set(ia_answers)
```

You are replace `users_says.set()` and `ia_says.set()` resets the complete Labels , with the new value. Instead you should get the old value and append the new value to it and set it back, Example -

```
user_says.set(user_says.get() + input_get + "\n")
ia_says.set(ia_says.get() + ia_answers + "\n")
```

---

Or you can also create a new label for each new event and add it to the `LabelFrame` . Example -

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

ia_answers= "trolol\n"
input_frame = LabelFrame(window, text="User :", borderwidth=4)
input_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(input_frame, text=input_user)
input_field.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

ia_frame = LabelFrame(window, text="Discussion",borderwidth = 15, height = 100, width = 100)
ia_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP)

user_says = StringVar()
user_text = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=user_says, anchor = NE, justify =   RIGHT, 

bg="white") 
user_text.pack(fill=X) 

ia_says = StringVar()
ia_text = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=ia_says, anchor = NW, justify = LEFT, bg="white") 
ia_text.pack(fill=X) 

user_texts = []
ia_texts = []
user_says_list = []
ia_says_list = []
def Enter_pressed(event):
    """Took the current string in the Entry field."""
    input_get = input_field.get()
    input_user.set("")
    user_says1 = StringVar()
    user_says1.set(input_get + "\n")
    user_text1 = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=user_says1, anchor = NE, justify =   RIGHT, 

bg="white") 
    user_text1.pack(fill=X)
    user_texts.append(user_text1)
    user_says_list.append(user_says1)
    ia_says1 = StringVar()
    ia_says1.set(ia_answers)
    ia_text1 = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=ia_says1, anchor = NW, justify = LEFT, 

bg="white") 
    ia_text1.pack(fill=X)
    ia_texts.append(ia_text1)
    ia_says_list.append(ia_says1)

input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, but when I do that, the user input isn't alternate with the IA answer :/ it's like User User IA IA and not User IA User IA

Comment: If so, for each new item, create a new label and add it to the label frame.

Comment: I've tried unsuccesfully, have you an advice or an exemple ?

Comment: Please check out the latest , if you want more fine control. set the correct width/height for the labels